# Popper: modifier "popoverArrowMargins" provided an invalid "fn" property, expected "function" but got "undefined"

Tags: java, reactjs, ethereum, solidity, web3-java

I keep receiving this Popper: modifier error when I hover my cursor over an OverlayTrigger.

The OverlayTrigger displays and operates fine.  I just keep getting the Popper: modifier for no reason.  I believe it might be a bug with the OverlayTrigger that is currently being resolved, but thought I would check to make sure I wasnt missing something here.

Comment: The first hit when googling your error message is a github bug report.

Comment: Also this didn't have anything to do with Java, Ethereum or Web3 does it? It's best not to add irrelevant tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The popper: modifier error shows up on the Developer JavaScript Console inside of the React App.  I am a new user of Stack Overflow and Github.  If this is already listed in a github bug report, does that mean that this is a known issue within the program and I should just ignore this error?

Answer (score 1):

had similar issue, solved by changing the dayjs version to "dayjs": "^1.8.36", with 1.11.1 the console warning appears and Overlay/Popover works not properly

Comment: Updating days to 1.11.1 removed the warning. Thank you very much!